# Relations Model Product With Color in Asp .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a model in the name of color and relation it to the product model.
My question is, is it better to separate the color model or does it fit in the product model itself? Which is more principled and professional?
If the color model is to be made separately, what is its relation to the product model ,one by one or Or is the list of product models relation to the color model and the list of color models to the products?

Like the following example:

```html
ProductModel:
public List<ProductColor> ProductColors { get; set; }

ColorModel:

public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Comment: I think you can separate color models, and the relationship between Product and Color models should be a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bad idea to separate colors model because in this way you can use colors entity at multiple places in your application.

Regarding the second question, should it be one-to-one or one-to-many then it depends actually. Some products like "Lays" comes with multiple colors depedning on the flavor. So you can create a one-to-many relation where product table will contains ColorId

```
public class Color 
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

and

```
public class Product
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("Color")]
   public int ColorId {get;set;}
   public Color Color {get;set;}
 }
```